# Bad OpenGL performance when running the game windowed

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, games

I'm playing Dust Racing 2D (https://sourceforge.net/projects/dustrac/) on Ubuntu 13.10.

The problem is that the performance is bad when running the game in a window. The fullscreen mode is perfectly smooth, though. My PC has a rather new NVIDIA's GTX 650 graphics card with proprietary drivers.

Why I'm asking this is that the game runs at 60 fps WINDOWED on my SLOWER Ubuntu 12.04 laptop, which has Intel's integrated HD 3500! The GTX 650 should be insanely fast compared to HD 3500.

Is there anything I could do to this? Could it be that Intel's drivers just work better with Unity and Qt (the game uses Qt)? Regression after 12.04?